# Is it possible to make menu contributions in javafx based Eclipse RCP applications?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-rcp, e4, efxclipse

On SWT based eclipse rcp application I can build a Plugin B that contributing UI elements to plugin A, in most cases this is a main rcp application plugin.

For example I can contribute with a plugin a new Menu to my main menu.

This works awesome. Actually I do some research with JavaFX basded RCP Applications.

For some reason a UI contribution not work for me. I checked out some javafx eclipse rcp application from github, but all of them do entire UI staff in a single main plugin.

Is it that generelly possible to builid multi plugin javafx rcp application?

Comment: JavaFX RCPs are usually 'e4' application using the e(fx)clipse code. e4 applications using the *.e4xmi files to do menu contributions.

Comment: Yes, I have an e4 JavaFX RCP Application created with e(fx)clipse

Comment: So you should be able to use a fragment.e4xmi in other plug-ins. I don't use JavaFX so I can't say if there are any special requirements.

Comment: I did it, I built a sample application exactly how I did it with SWT. With the difference that in my SWT example everything works. But not in javafx example application. I have a second plugin project with a fragment.e4xmi.

Comment: Yes, you can contribute to a JavaFX e4 application using fragments. We have a large JavaFX e4 application which makes heavy use of this feature. If you are having difficulties, you could post a question with the details.

Comment: Verdy difficult to ask more detailed, because I absolutley dont know, what is going wrong. No errors, nothing. Its just not working. It is possible that you upload on github an Example with new fx rcp project?